# Is this an actual patent? WO2012046284A2

Tags: claims, application, rules

In reference to the patent: [WO2012046284A2](https://www.google.com/patents/WO2012046284A2)

There is no technology described in this patent. There are wrong descriptions of scientific theories and many other errors. It even invokes religious concepts as part of the reasons why it should work yet fails to give any technical description of how it will work. In effect, it is completely vacuous.

Comment: You are citing an application and one can write (almost) everything into an application - it is checked before granting, not before publication. I'm voting to close because there is no question here.

Comment: @DonQuiKong Although not a very good question, there is a question. Your comment is reasonable and could stand (with a little extra description) as an answer. It may  be a duplicate as I seem to remember other questions regarding applications (and even patents) that are unlikely technology wise.